# How can I track when a Linux Azure App Service is Stopping and Stopped?

Tags: asp.net, linux, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-appservice

I have a basic ASP.NET application hosted as an Azure linux app service and I want to track when the service is Starting, Started, Stopping and Stopped. This works great for Starting and Started but when it comes to Stopping and Stopped it doesn't appear that the linux app service calls the necessary OnStopping and OnStopped methods.

[Code for the Hosted Service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aPwZt.png)

```
internal class LifetimeEventsHostedService : IHostedService
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;
    private readonly IHostApplicationLifetime _appLifetime;
    public LifetimeEventsHostedService(
    ILogger<LifetimeEventsHostedService> logger,
    IHostApplicationLifetime appLifetime)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _appLifetime = appLifetime;
    }
    public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("***Starting Service Async");
        _appLifetime.ApplicationStarted.Register(OnStarted);
        _appLifetime.ApplicationStopping.Register(OnStopping);
        _appLifetime.ApplicationStopped.Register(OnStopped);

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("***Stopping Service Async");
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
    private void OnStarted()
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("***Starting Service. OnStarted has been called.");
    }

    private void OnStopping()
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("***Stopping Service. OnStopping has been called.");
    }
    private void OnStopped()
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("***Stopped Service. OnStopped has been called.");
    }
}
```

The above code works fine for Starting and Started but not for Stopping and Stopped. It also works fine in a Windows App Service. Is this a bug with Linux App Services? Is there anyway to circumvent this?

Comment: Where are the logs written to?

Comment: Similar behavior on my AppService. Looks like `Stop` on Linux just kills it, no log messages from graceful shutdown (as visible on windows).

Comment: @sharpener or seanhl7soup, did you able to solve this?

Comment: Yes, don't deploy as AppService. Instead use Linux VM and manage it yourself.